# How to use Tapku on my projects in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode4, tapku

I'm trying to use the amazing [Tapku library for iOS](http://tapku.com) on my projects in XCode 4. Previously, there was this easy step-by-step guide to follow [here](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/How-To-Use-This-Library). XCode 4 is totally different and I can't get it to work. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

reference the doc here: [Adding Tapku to Your Project in XCode 4](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-Tapku-to-Your-Project-in-XCode-4)

Comment: i need to add it to XCode 5 , is there any tutorial explain that